# Forcing an alarm handler to be called every 1 second (in C)

Tags: c, unix, signals, alarm

The main idea of what I'm trying to do:

My goal is that alarm_handler will be called every 1 second, despite of other signals (in this case, SIGUSR2). For that, I wrote alarm(1) before pause() statement.

But, what is happening in-fact, is that if I recieve SIGUSR2 signal many times, alarm_handler is never called (while I do want it to be called each 1 second).

Note: I do not want to ignore SIGUSR2 signals. I want them to be done, but I have to make sure that alarm_handler is done each 1 second.

Here is the main:

```
int main(int argc, const char* argv[])
{
signal(SIGUSR2, sig_readPipe);
signal(SIGALRM, alarm_handler);

do
{
    alarm(1);
    pause();
}while(stopFlag);

return 0;
}
```

And here are the signal handlers:

```
void sig_readPipe(int sig)
{
signal(SIGUSR2, sig_readPipe);
.
.
.
}

void alarm_handler(int sig)
{
signal(SIGALRM, alarm_handler);
.
.
.
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Put whatever it is that needs to be processed every second into a separate function, and in that function, set a global counter to the current time. Every time any signal handler is called, it should check if the counter matches the current second, and if not, then call run_this_every_second().

Comment: how to set a counter to global time?

Comment: didnt work for me.. could you please write how it should be done?